# Does Redis's allkeys-lru maxmemory policy require keys to have expiration set?

Tags: php, apache, redis

Does Redis's allkeys-lru maxmemory policy require all keys in the database to have expiration set?

What's the failover when there isn't an expiration set?

Comment: It'll kill off the least recently used non-expiring key. I found this out because AWS ElastiCache defaults to `volatile-lru` and we ran out of space, and switching to `allkeys-lru` fixed that nicely.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've been using allkeys-lru and sometimes it seems to fail to delete required space for the next key, and redis crashes

Comment: That seems odd and doesn't fit with my experience or the docs. Are you sure the config change is actually in effect? What do the logs say after one of these crashes?

Comment: @ceejayoz I looked at the log and it only has bootup log inside - nothing on the crashes. I do "info" on redis-cli to check that it's in effect ... and indeed it is. used_memory_peak_rss was far above maxmemory... perhaps there is a memory fragmentation?

Comment: Check your main server syslogs, with a particular focus on anything that says `oom`. I'd bet your server is running out of RAM before Redis does, and that the out-of-memory killer is terminating Redis (being a memory-heavy process) as a result.

Comment: will check. Thanks @ceejayoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allkeys-*` eviction policies don't care about TTL.

Crashes and unexpected behaviors (looking at you @ceehayoz) should be reported to the project's repo, although EC is a service and the Redis version they're using may or may not be the same as the official OSS project.

Comment: You get to pick which Redis version to use with your Elasticache instance, and it crashing (a misnomer - I didn't say it crashed, our Laravel install just couldn't store any more sessions and threw errors) in *my* case was expected behavior (just one I wasn't are of). Redis being killed by OOM as I theorize shouldn't be reported to the Redis project, as it has nothing to do with them.

Comment: Ah - ok, I'm relieved, thanks for the clarification.